# I am using multi image metabox plugin but I did get how to display the images in templete?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

please help me...
here is plugin url http://wordpress.org/plugins/multi-image-metabox/
I am using this plugin but after uploading images.

I need to get those images on template...

code to display the images on single post page.

Comment: Did you have a look at [Installation](http://wordpress.org/plugins/multi-image-metabox/installation/) and/or [Other Notes](http://wordpress.org/plugins/multi-image-metabox/other_notes/)? This is (well) explained on the plugin site.

Comment: Why? The native media functions enable you to do pretty much anything. Why you need a plugin? Where exactly do you want to display the images?

Answer (score 0):

The plugins own installation tab lists the functions to use within a template file.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/multi-image-metabox/installation/

The instructions are generic so you'll need to figure out what to use and where to use them based on how you want it all to look on your site.

Comment: To be clear this does involve PHP. However it's a copy and paste of the functions mentioned on said installation tab so even without PHP skills it is possible to get something happening.

Answer (score 0):

Put this function miu_get_images($post_id) in your template file. It returns array of images.

```
<?php 
$images = miu_get_images($post_id); 

//Sample output
Array
(
    [0] => http://www.example.com/image-1.png
    [1] => http://www.example.com/image-2.png
)

?>
```

Please refer this link [reference](http://wordpress.org/plugins/multi-image-upload/other_notes/#miu_get_images%28%29)